# How can I use JavaScript OnBlur() in HTML div?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a menu and I can open and close the menu clicking on a tag. It works. 
Also I use OnBlur(). Actually it works too but When I click a div in the menu, OnBlur active, menu closes and div's onclick doesn't works. How can I fix this problem ?

In JavaScript Codes;

```
<script>
  function Acc_Show() {
    var q = document.getElementById("he-my");
    q.style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("my-account-btn").focus();
    document.getElementById("my-account-btn").setAttribute("onclick", "Acc_Hide()");
  }
  function Acc_Hide() {
    var q = document.getElementById("he-my");
    q.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("my-account-btn").setAttribute("onclick", "Acc_Show()");
  }
</script>
```

In HTML codes;

```
<a id="my-account-btn" href="javascript:;" onclick="Acc_Show()" onblur="Acc_Hide()">My Account</a>
```

My Menu's Image;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMg6n.png

**UPDATES** Additional Codes From OP:

```
<div class="he-myac" id="he-my" style="display:none;">
  <div id="my-account-wrapper">
    <div class="myaccount" onclick="GoAdress('test.aspx')">Test</div>  
    <br/>
    <div class="myaccount" onclick="GoAdress('settings.aspx')" >Settings</div>
    <br/>
    <div class="myaccount" onclick="GoAdress('log_out.aspx')">Log Out</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You don't need to set an onclick attribute with JavaScript, you can simply add a click event handler that invokes your function. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick

Comment: thank you but my main problem is not this. about OnBlur

Comment: So you mean after your function `Acc_Hide()` is called (triggered by an `onblur` event), the next click on your `my-account-btn` button doesn't trigger your `Acc_Show` function?

Comment: @BurakKaya That's why I made a comment, not an answer. I'm trying to help you write clean code that's easy to understand. What you currently have is honestly a mess. Javascript function names should be lower camel case: `showAccount` vs `Acc_Show`. You re-query the same element multiple times... waste of typing, performance and readability.

Comment: No. Think like this. I clicked my-account-btn and menu opened. then  I clicked a div (Div has onclick event) in the menu (inside). But div's onclick event doesn't work because when I click the div, onblur trigger and menu closes.

I wanna that when I click the div, works the div's onclick event.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan I have already know these. But I don't want to use like that. I can understand my command and when there is problem, I usually fix them. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this line `q.style.display = "";` in your `Acc_Show()` function is causing the issue. Try replace it with `q.style.display = "block";`.

When an `onblur` event is triggered, your `Acc_Hide()` function hides your `<div>` by calling `q.style.display = "none";`. Then the next click on `my-account-btn` triggers your `Acc_Show()` function, which set your `q.style.display` to an empty string. That doesn't unhide your `<div>` block.

Comment: @BurakKaya Please post your other relevant codes such as the `div` you were talking about in your comment.

Comment: '<div class="he-myac" id="he-my" style="display:none;">

<div id="my-account-wrapper">
<div class="myaccount" onclick="GoAdress('test.aspx')">Test</div> <br/>
<div class="myaccount" onclick="GoAdress('settings.aspx')" >Settings</div> <br/>
<div class="myaccount" onclick="GoAdress('log_out.aspx')">Log Out</div>
</div>'

Comment: @BurakKaya So what you meant is when you click on `myaccount` inside the menu, the `onblur` event of `my-account-btn` is triggered?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So I just want that when i click myaccount, onblur doesn't be active and run GoAddress JavaScript.

Comment: @BurakKaya Try remove `document.getElementById("my-account-btn").focus();` from your `Acc_Show()`.